# <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern> in spring 2.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i am making a sample program in spring mvc from http://maestric.com/doc/java/spring/hello_world.
i used `<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>`  in spring 2.0.

i also changed in springmvc-servlet.xml:`<bean name="/hello_world.jsp" class="springmvc.web.HelloWorldController"/>`

but it is not run.

when i use`<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>` it is run.
why we use`<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>`  in spring 2.0 ?

Can i use other than *.html ?

Comment: if i use  *.do instead of *.html in <servlet-mapping>
and in springmvc-servlet.xml:
<bean name="/*.do" class="springmvc.web.HelloWorldController"/>
then public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) are not called

Can i use other url-pattern instead of *.html sothat ModelAndView handleRequest method can be execute.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same exercise as in the link, the problem **may be** because of

```
<welcome-file>
  jsp/index.jsp
</welcome-file>
```

Since index.jsp is not mapped to any controller. You can post your error for more investigation.

Comment: i am not using the sample exactly. my Web.xml is:
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>  
  </servlet-mapping>  
 <welcome-file-list>  
    <welcome-file>/jsp/Hello.jsp</welcome-file>  
  </welcome-file-list>

springmvc-servlet.xml:
<bean name="/*.html" class="springmvc.web.HelloWorldController"/>